# How to use React with Yup Validation (Without Formik)

Tags: reactjs, yup

Any idea how can I do a React input validation using Yup (without Formik)?

I couldn't find online any good example. Thanks

Comment: up is a JavaScript object schema validator and object parser. It is not required to use Formik.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `cast()` if u want to use yup without formik, see example :

```
let yup = require('yup');

let schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  age: yup
    .number()
    .required()
    .positive()
    .integer(),
  email: yup.string().email(),
  website: yup.string().url(),
  createdOn: yup.date().default(function() {
    return new Date();
  }),
});

// check validity
schema
  .isValid({
    name: 'jimmy',
    age: 24,
  })
  .then(function(valid) {
    valid; // => true
  });

// you can try and type cast objects to the defined schema
schema.cast({
  name: 'jimmy',
  age: '24',
  createdOn: '2014-09-23T19:25:25Z',
});
// => { name: 'jimmy', age: 24, createdOn: Date }
```

Answer (score -4):

Formik handles forms in react, binding the input tags to a model, that model can contain validators which can be Yum or any other form of validation.

If you don't want to use Formik then you can use another Form handling library for react such as [FormState](https://formstate.github.io/#/).

If you don't want to use a form handling library at all then you have to do it all [by hand](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Comment: He certainly wants to use yum you are recommending unrelated stuff.

Comment: you mean yummy ? :)